# Cant remove an element clicking a particular button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I build an User interface for trading platform. Where I placed a draggable widget for order placing , it may Buy or Sell Order. both the button has same class for Buy and Sell . Also have another Button For Cancel. All When trying to remove codes of the widget getting some error When it is Sell widget.

When clicking Buy and Cancel Button everything ok. After buy widget code is removed properly. But when trying same thing on Sell Widget all functions are getting fired but cant remove widget codes. I want to destroy that window after placing the order. I can destroy the codes clicking the Cancel Button.When triggering same codes after placing order it is not working.

code is also working properly in console. Anyone can suggest me how to do that ?

```js
    $(document).on('click', '.actions .button-orange', function(){
    //

    if (style== null||style== 'undefined') {
        style = 'top: 141px; left: 413px; width: 550px; height: 277px; z-index: 1; opacity: 1;'
    }
    $('.vdr').attr('style', style);
    $('.vdr').addClass('active');
    $('.vdr').html(sellButton);
    trans = 'sell';


});
$(document).on('click', '.actions .button-blue', function(){
    //

    if (style== null||style== 'undefined') {
        style = 'top: 141px; left: 413px; width: 550px; height: 277px; z-index: 1; opacity: 1;'
    }
    $('.vdr').attr('style', style);
    $('.vdr').addClass('active');
    $('.vdr').html(buyButton);
    trans = 'buy';

});

$(document).on('click', '.place', function() {
  var trans = $.trim($('.transaction-type').html());
  if (trans == 'sell') {
    sellOrderExec(); //executing
    $('.order-window-draggable').html(''); //not executing
    console.log("working");//prints 'working' in the console
  } else if (trans == 'buy') {
    buyOrderExec(); //executing
    $('.order-window-draggable').html(''); //executing
  }
})
```

here is the html for buy form widget

```html
<div class="order-window-cover buy variety-regular">
  <div class="draggable-area"></div>
  <form class="order-window buy">
    <div class="dock"> <span class="icon icon-full"></span> </div>
    <div class="head row buy">
      <div class="nine columns">
        <div class="instruments-info"> <span class="transaction-type">buy</span> <span class="tradingsymbol">                                          SBIN                                    </span> <span class="quantity">× 1 Qty</span>
        </div>
        <div class="last-price"> <span>₹</span>284.9 on NSE </div>
      </div>
      <div class="three columns text-right transaction-type-switch">
        <div class="su-switch-group">
          <input id="switch-1455" type="checkbox" stateon="SELL" stateoff="BUY" label="" class="su-switch" value="BUY"> <label for="switch-1455" class="su-switch-control"></label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="row row-1">
        <div class="four columns">
          <div class="su-radio-group products">
            <div class="product su-radio-wrap" rules="[object Object]" data-balloon="Intraday squareoff with extra leverage" data-balloon-pos="up"> <input id="radio-1457" type="radio" title="Intraday squareoff with extra leverage" label="MIS" class="su-radio" value="MIS"> <label for="radio-1457" class="su-radio-label">MIS</label> </div>
            <div class="product su-radio-wrap" rules="[object Object]" data-balloon="Cash and carry. Delivery based trades" data-balloon-pos="up"> <input id="radio-1458" type="radio" title="Cash and carry. Delivery based trades" label="CNC" class="su-radio" value="CNC"> <label for="radio-1458" class="su-radio-label">CNC</label> </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="eight columns text-right">
          <div class="su-radio-group order-types">
            <div class="order-type su-radio-wrap" rules="[object Object]" data-balloon="Market" data-balloon-pos="up"> <input id="radio-1460" type="radio" title="Market" label="MARKET" class="su-radio" value="MARKET"> <label for="radio-1460" class="su-radio-label">MARKET</label> </div>
            <div class="order-type su-radio-wrap" rules="[object Object]" data-balloon="Limit" data-balloon-pos="up"> <input id="radio-1461" type="radio" title="Limit" label="LIMIT" class="su-radio" value="LIMIT"> <label for="radio-1461" class="su-radio-label">LIMIT</label> </div>
            <div class="order-type su-radio-wrap" rules="[object Object]" data-balloon="Stoploss" data-balloon-pos="up"> <input id="radio-1462" type="radio" title="Stoploss" label="SL" class="su-radio" value="SL"> <label for="radio-1462" class="su-radio-label">SL</label> </div>
            <div class="order-type su-radio-wrap" rules="[object Object]" data-balloon="Stoploss market" data-balloon-pos="up"> <input id="radio-1463" type="radio" title="Stoploss market" label="SL-M" class="su-radio" value="SL-M"> <label for="radio-1463" class="su-radio-label">SL-M</label> </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row row-2">
        <div prop="quantity" class="quantity input-field three columns">
          <div class="su-input-group su-static-label"> <label class="su-input-label su-visible">Qty.</label> <input type="number" placeholder="" autocorrect="off" min="1" step="1" noerror="true" staticlabel="true" animate="true" label="Qty." rules="[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]"
              dynamicwidthsize="8">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div prop="price" class="price input-field three columns">
          <div class="su-input-group su-static-label disabled"> <label class="su-input-label">Price</label> <input type="number" placeholder="" autocorrect="off" min="0" step="0.05" disabled="disabled" noerror="true" staticlabel="true" animate="true" label="Price" rules="[object Object]" dynamicwidthsize="8">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div prop="triggerPrice" class="trigger-price input-field three columns">
          <div class="su-input-group su-static-label disabled"> <label class="su-input-label">Trigger price</label> <input type="number" placeholder="" autocorrect="off" min="0" step="0.05" disabled="disabled" noerror="true" staticlabel="true" animate="true" label="Trigger price" rules="[object Object],[object Object]" dynamicwidthsize="8">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div prop="disclosedQuantity" class="disclosed-quantity input-field three columns">
          <div class="su-input-group su-static-label"> <label class="su-input-label">Disclosed qty.</label> <input type="number" placeholder="" autocorrect="off" min="0" step="1" noerror="true" staticlabel="true" animate="true" label="Disclosed qty." rules="[object Object],[object Object]" dynamicwidthsize="8">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row row-4">
        <div class="advanced-options-toggle seven columns">   
          <a href="#" class="text-xsmall">
            More options
            <span class="icon icon-chevron-down"></span>                                    
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="actions five columns text-right"> 
          <button type="submit" class="place button-blue">
            <span>Buy</span>
            <button type="button" class="button-outline cancel">Cancel</button> 
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Here is the code for Sell form Window

```
<div class="order-window-cover sell variety-regular">
  <div class="draggable-area"></div>
  <form class="order-window sell">
    <div class="dock"> <span class="icon icon-full"></span> </div>
    <div class="head row sell">
      <div class="nine columns">
        <div class="instruments-info"> 
          <span class="transaction-type">sell</span> 
          <span class="tradingsymbol">SRTRANSFIN</span> 
          <span class="quantity">× 1 Qty</span>
        </div>
        <div class="last-price"> <span>₹</span>967.15 on NSE </div>
      </div>
      <div class="three columns text-right transaction-type-switch">
        <div class="su-switch-group">
          <input id="switch-532" type="checkbox" stateon="SELL" stateoff="BUY" label="" class="su-switch" value="SELL" checked="checked"> 
          <label for="switch-532" class="su-switch-control"></label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="row row-1">
        <div class="four columns">
          <div class="su-radio-group products">
            <div class="product su-radio-wrap" rules="[object Object]" data-balloon="Intraday squareoff with extra leverage" data-balloon-pos="up"> <input id="radio-534" type="radio" title="Intraday squareoff with extra leverage" label="MIS" class="su-radio" value="MIS"> <label for="radio-534" class="su-radio-label">MIS</label> </div>
            <div class="product su-radio-wrap" rules="[object Object]" data-balloon="Cash and carry. Delivery based trades" data-balloon-pos="up"> <input id="radio-535" type="radio" title="Cash and carry. Delivery based trades" label="CNC" class="su-radio" value="CNC"> <label for="radio-535" class="su-radio-label">CNC</label> </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="eight columns text-right">
          <div class="su-radio-group order-types">
            <div class="order-type su-radio-wrap" rules="[object Object]" data-balloon="Market" data-balloon-pos="up"> <input id="radio-537" type="radio" title="Market" label="MARKET" class="su-radio" value="MARKET"> <label for="radio-537" class="su-radio-label">MARKET</label> </div>
            <div class="order-type su-radio-wrap" rules="[object Object]" data-balloon="Limit" data-balloon-pos="up"> <input id="radio-538" type="radio" title="Limit" label="LIMIT" class="su-radio" value="LIMIT"> <label for="radio-538" class="su-radio-label">LIMIT</label> </div>
            <div class="order-type su-radio-wrap" rules="[object Object]" data-balloon="Stoploss" data-balloon-pos="up"> <input id="radio-539" type="radio" title="Stoploss" label="SL" class="su-radio" value="SL"> <label for="radio-539" class="su-radio-label">SL</label> </div>
            <div class="order-type su-radio-wrap" rules="[object Object]" data-balloon="Stoploss market" data-balloon-pos="up"> <input id="radio-540" type="radio" title="Stoploss market" label="SL-M" class="su-radio" value="SL-M"> <label for="radio-540" class="su-radio-label">SL-M</label> </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row row-2">
        <div prop="quantity" class="quantity input-field three columns">
          <div class="su-input-group su-static-label"> <label class="su-input-label su-visible">Qty.</label> <input type="number" placeholder="" autocorrect="off" min="1" step="1" noerror="true" staticlabel="true" animate="true" label="Qty." rules="[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]" dynamicwidthsize="8">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div prop="price" class="price input-field three columns">
          <div class="su-input-group su-static-label disabled"> <label class="su-input-label">Price</label> <input type="number" placeholder="" autocorrect="off" min="0" step="0.05" disabled="disabled" noerror="true" staticlabel="true" animate="true" label="Price" rules="[object Object]" dynamicwidthsize="8">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div prop="triggerPrice" class="trigger-price input-field three columns">
          <div class="su-input-group su-static-label disabled"> <label class="su-input-label">Trigger price</label> <input type="number" placeholder="" autocorrect="off" min="0" step="0.05" disabled="disabled" noerror="true" staticlabel="true" animate="true" label="Trigger price" rules="[object Object],[object Object]" dynamicwidthsize="8">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div prop="disclosedQuantity" class="disclosed-quantity input-field three columns">
          <div class="su-input-group su-static-label"> <label class="su-input-label">Disclosed qty.</label> <input type="number" placeholder="" autocorrect="off" min="0" step="1" noerror="true" staticlabel="true" animate="true" label="Disclosed qty." rules="[object Object],[object Object]" dynamicwidthsize="8">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row row-4">
        <div class="advanced-options-toggle seven columns"> <a href="#" class="text-xsmall">            More options             <span class="icon icon-chevron-down"></span>          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="actions five columns text-right"> <button type="submit" class="place button-orange">            <span>Sell</span>   </button>
          <button type="button" class="button-outline cancel">Cancel</button> </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Here is the div where these codes are added dynamically

```
<div data-v-130adaec="" class="vdr order-window-draggable active" style="top: 108px; left: 615px; width: 550px; height: 277px; z-index: 1; opacity: 1;"></div>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198692/discussion-on-question-by-mijanur-rahaman-cant-remove-an-element-clicking-a-part).

Answer (score 0):

I got the bug. It was triggering another function for additional class of the button, thats i was not getting all properties. Thanks to all